# Cartoon with a boy who goes to another world, where he fights monsters and meets a boy and a girl

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched some episodes of this cartoon a long time ago. There was this boy who could go to another world (or dimension) through a theatre (I think) where he would fight monsters (maybe).

I remember that he had two companions, a girl and another boy; the other boy was short of height and the girl was really good at fighting. Both his companions were from that other world. The main character would go and meet them when there was a problem and his friends sent him an alert.

I'm not sure but I think the boy's grandpa was also involved in the story.

I don't remember the motive or the plot, appearance (in that much clarity) or the main story of the show.

(I think the girl from that other world carried a staff (not too sure)).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a long time ago?"  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for identification questions to see if they help you remember anything else.  You don't say it's anime, but there might be a few more cues [here too](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like the ***[Matt Hatter Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Hatter_Chronicles)***.

> *Matt Hatter Chronicles*, is a British-Canadian-Indian animated series produced by UK's Platinum Films, Arc Productions, and Dream Mill. It began airing on Teletoon on 8 September 2012.
>
> It aired on Cartoon Network in India on 19 May 2014. Season 3 premiered 13 April 2015 on Cartoon Network (India).

The main character, Matt, discovers a portal to a multiverse of other worlds in his family's movie theatre. His grandfather becomes trapped in said multiverse, and Matt goes in to rescue him:

> Matt Hatter is an ordinary child who discovers that the monsters of his family's horror movies are alive in another dimension called "the Multiverse", controlled by the nefarious Lord Tenoroc. This dimension can only be accessed through the Notting Hill Coronet, his family's movie theater. With his grandfather Alfred trapped inside the Multiverse, Matt, along with his new friends Roxie and Gomez, must capture the movie monsters, save Alfred, and restore peace to the Multiverse.

His main allies are Roxie and Gomez, whom he meets shortly after venturing into the multiverse for the first time. Roxie wields a staff, and Gomez is a little shorter than the other two:

> - Roxanna "Roxie" Alexis (voiced by Larissa Murray): **A 13-year old pink skinned and magenta haired girl from the Multiverse** who is a Tracker of Team Hatter. **She wields a staff that** was created from the ancient Tree of Life by Gomez, and holds an amber crystal on the end that calls Matt when the Multiverse is in danger.
> - Alejandro Diego Gomez Montero (voiced by Marcel McCalla): **A 12-year-old boy from the Multiverse** who is the Keeper of Team Hatter. He wields a weapon from the Cave of Secrets that used to belong to his father.

Here's the first episode. You can find more on YouTube:

Comment: Was just adding this answer myself +1, you beat me to it....

Comment: Whether this is right or not, it's a gold badge!