# Cartoon where kid enters different world via cinema screen

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

So, I’m 19 in a month or two and this cartoon was where his parents owned a cinema and he would enter the screen and fight the main monster of that movie.

I remember exactly what it looked like but I cannot, for the life of me remember the name.

Comment: "I’m 19 in a month or 2" and how old were you when you watch this cartoon? I.e. how long ago did you watch it? That's the important part.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Matt Hatter Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Hatter_Chronicles)*** (2011-2015)...?

> Matt Hatter is an ordinary child who discovers that the monsters of his family's horror movies are alive in another dimension called "the Multiverse", controlled by the nefarious Lord Tenoroc. This dimension can only be accessed through the Notting Hill Coronet, his family's movie theater. With his grandfather Alfred trapped inside the Multiverse, Matt, along with his new friends Roxie and Gomez, must capture the movie monsters, save Alfred, and restore peace to the Multiverse.

The main character, [Matt Hatter](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Matthew_Luke_Hatter), moves home from the US to London with his parents and discovers that the screen in his grandfather, [Alfred](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Alfred_Hatter)'s, movie theatre, the [Coronet](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Coronet), is a portal to the '[Multiverse](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Multiverse),' another dimension made up of twelve realms.

At the start of each episode, the main antagonist of the show, [Lord Tenoroc](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Lord_Tenoroc), releases a horror movie villain/monster from hexagonal discs called [Life Cells](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Cell), to achieve some sinister objective or other within the Multiverse.

It used to be the job of Matt's grandfather to capture these villains/monsters, with the assistance of [Roxie](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Roxanna_Alexis) and [Gomez](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Alejandro_Diego_Gomez_Monteros), a pair of kids from the Multiverse, but Alfred has been trapped by Tenoroc, so now Matt has to take over.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/251517/20774

Comment: This is it,                                           Thank you

Comment: @Futuristic Ninja - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.